# ZwAssignProcessToJobObject : ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: delphi, winapi, kill-process

I'm trying finalize a determinated process ([**reference**](http://www.360doc.com/content/13/1130/16/9200790_333435140.shtml)) but before it i need `ZwAssignProcessToJobObject()`, I made this following small code to demonstrate my problem,  where `Status` is returning **0xC0000022** (*ACCESS_DENIED*). Is there a way to solve it?

```
type
  NTSTATUS = cardinal;
  PClientId = ^TClientId;
  TClientId = record
    UniqueProcess: THandle;
    UniqueThread: THandle;
end;

PObjectAttributes = ^TObjectAttributes;
  TObjectAttributes = packed record
  Length: Cardinal;
  RootDirectory: THandle;
  ObjectName: PUnicodeString;
  Attributes: Cardinal;
  SecurityDescriptor: Pointer;
  SecurityQualityOfService: Pointer;
 end;
  OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES = ^TObjectAttributes;
  POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES = ^OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES;

const
  STATUS_SUCCESS = $00000000;

var
 Status: NTSTATUS;

function CreateJobObjectW(lpJobAttributes: PSecurityAttributes; lpName: LPCWSTR): THANDLE; stdcall;external kernel32 name 'CreateJobObjectW' ;
function ZwAssignProcessToJobObject(hJob, hProcess: THANDLE): NTSTATUS; stdcall; external 'ntdll.dll';
function IsProcessInJob(ProcessHandle, JobHandle: THANDLE; var Result_: BOOL): BOOL; stdcall; external kernel32 name 'IsProcessInJob';
function ZwTerminateJobObject(JobHandle: THANDLE; ExitStatus: NTSTATUS): NTSTATUS; stdcall; external 'ntdll.dll';
function ZwOpenProcess(phProcess:PDWORD; AccessMask:DWORD; ObjectAttributes:PObjectAttributes; ClientID:PClientID): NTStatus; stdcall; external 'ntdll.dll' name 'ZwOpenProcess';
function ZwClose(Handle: THandle): NTSTATUS; stdcall;external 'ntdll.dll';

function MyZwOpenProcess(PID: Integer):THandle;
var
cid: TClientId;
atr: TObjectAttributes;
begin
atr.Length := SizeOf(OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES);
atr.RootDirectory := 0;
atr.ObjectName := nil;
atr.Attributes := 0;
atr.SecurityDescriptor := nil;
atr.SecurityQualityOfService := nil;
cid.UniqueProcess := PID;
cid.UniqueThread := 0;
ZwOpenProcess(@Result,PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,@atr,@cid);
end;

Procedure CloseProcessByHandle(hProcess:Thandle);
var
h:Thandle;
bInJob: LongBool;
begin
h := CreateJobObjectW(nil,'foo');
Status := ZwAssignProcessToJobObject(h,hProcess);
if (Status = STATUS_SUCCESS) then
begin
  ZwTerminateJobObject(h,0);
end;
  ZwClose(h);
end;

////////// ButtonClick event (usage) ///////////

var
  closeProcess: Thandle;
 begin
  closeProcess := MyZwOpenProcess(2980);
  CloseProcessByHandle(closeProcess);
  Showmessage('0x'+ inttostr(inttohex(Status,8)));
end;
```

Comment: look for src code of [NtAssignProcessToJobObject](https://github.com/mic101/windows/blob/master/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/ps/psjob.c#L265). it can return `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` by several reasons. most possible in your case - if process already in job or if job sessionid different from process session id. from your code unclear - what is process you use. and why you doing what doing, instead simply terminate process

Comment: @RbMm, thank you. solved!

Comment: @flash - If you're not interested in posting/receiving an answer consider deleting the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
uses
  tlhelp32;

type
  NTSTATUS = cardinal;

function ZwTerminateProcess(ProcessHandle: dword; ExitStatus: dword): NTSTATUS;
  stdcall; external 'ntdll.dll';
function ZwClose(Handle: THandle): NTSTATUS; stdcall; external 'ntdll.dll';
function ZwDuplicateObject(SourceProcessHandle, SourceHandle,
  TargetProcessHandle, TargetHandle, DesiredAccess, HandleAttributes,
  Options: LongInt): LongInt stdcall;
  external 'NTDLL.DLL' name 'ZwDuplicateObject';

procedure Kill;
const
  Arr: array [1 .. 4] of PChar = ('cs.exe', '', '', '');
var
  ContinueLoop: BOOL;
  FSnapshotHandle: THandle;
  pe: PROCESSENTRY32;
  ProcessHandle: LongInt;
  i: Integer;
begin
  FSnapshotHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  pe.dwSize := SizeOf(PROCESSENTRY32);
  if (Process32First(FSnapshotHandle, pe)) then
  begin
    while (Process32Next(FSnapshotHandle, pe)) do
    begin
      for i := 1 to High(Arr) do
      begin
        if (UpperCase(ExtractFileName(pe.szExeFile)) = UpperCase(Arr[i])) then
        begin
          ProcessHandle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, False,
            pe.th32ProcessID);
          ZwDuplicateObject(GetCurrentProcess, ProcessHandle, GetCurrentProcess,
            Integer(@ProcessHandle), PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 1);
          ZwTerminateProcess(ProcessHandle, 0);
          ZwClose(ProcessHandle);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  CloseHandle(FSnapshotHandle);
end;
```

Comment: Solution to what? Do you mind explaining why not use `TerminateProcess`? and what's with that `Arr` holding empty strings compared against the `pe.szExeFile`?

Comment: @kobik, this is a solution to kill any process (ex: rootkits).

Comment: In that case please specify this fact in your question.